# I cannot delete multiple emails on IBM Notes Social edition

Tags: lotus-notes

Somehow the multiple emails selected on IBM Notes Social edition do not get deleted when I hit the delete button. I am using Notes on MAC.

It worked well on Lotus Notes 8.5.3 but when I upgraded to Notes 9.0.1 recently, I lost this ability to delete multiple emails in one go.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Were you using the basic client before? The way documents are selected changed from the little check boxes to selecting with CMD-click. Also depending on your keyboard you hit the backspace ("<---") and not the delete key.

The other thing to check is if you have deletion rights in your ACL. From the menu "File->Application->Access Control", then click your name and make sure "Delete documents" is clicked on.

Comment: I haven't used 9.x yet but the 8.x prefs let you add the column back in if you want to do the old style document selection.